# Can't show variable value in a Text widget (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
_places.forEach((element) {
  final String name = element.name;
  print(element);
  places.add(Card(
      child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
          onTap: () {
            print('Card tapped.');
          },
          child: const SizedBox(
              width: 375,
              height: 100,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.00),
                child: Text(
                  name
                )
              )))));
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the variable `name` is giving an error when using it inside `Text`.

`Error: Not a constant expression.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try removing the **const** from **SizedBox**. SizedBox expecting data to be constant, but the variable **text** can change on runtime. **const** is used in a case the value is constant from compile time.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm allowed